# 404 Error on trying to enqueue a JS file

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have been trying to use wp_enqueue_script() to load a JS script into one of my pages but it keeps throwing a "Failed to load resource" 404 error in the console (running Chrome). My code is as follows:

myplugin.php:

```
function myplugin_load_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-testjs', (plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "scripts/myplugin-test.js"), array('jquery'), null, true );

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_load_script');

}
```

myplugin-test.js:

```
alert("Hello!");
```

I have checked the HTML  tag and the development tools and both of them display the correct URL (eg. wp-content/plugins/myplugin/scripts/myplugin-test.js).

I have also checked that the file does exist there and the name is correct, PHP throws no errors either. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. The action must be defined outside of the callback.

Also, you are using `plugin_dir_path()` function, which gets the path to plugin directoy in the filesystem of the server, not the url. You should use [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/) instead.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_load_script' );
function myplugin_load_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-testjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "scripts/myplugin-test.js", array('jquery'), null, true );

}
```

Comment: May I ask why the action needs to be above the function definition?

I also don't quite understand the difference between the path and the dir functions, in the browser console the <script> tag looks identical to the previous one.

Comment: Okay I actually missed the edit. The add_action() was meant to be outside of the function, after the closing curly bracket. My question on the path/dir difference still stands.

Comment: The `add_action()` needs to be outside the callback (function) your are defining for the action, either above or bellow it is your choice, but not inside the callback. The path in the filesystem is the location of the file/dir in the machine. For example, in an Apache server it tipically looks like `/home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`. In a Windows PC it may looks like `C:\users\dir`. If you got a identical value for dir path and dir url, I guess you just was lucky.